# C password validation?

Tags: c, validation, passwords

I'm being bugged right now because I'm making a little password validation thing in C.

the case is

1. It should have at least 8 characters entered
2. It should have at least 1 number
3. It should have at least 1 uppercase / lowercase letter.

For example:
if the rules are not complied it would show

Enter your password: doratheexplorer

```
NOT A GOOD PASSWORD 
NO DIGIT
NO UPPERCASE LETTER
```

else 
continue

how would I do something like this? do I need to use string.h?

Comment: Visit [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and see __How to Ask__.

Comment: @Ink Homework should be done by your own...

Comment: @ink good day to you..SO not doing homework for anyone.please try something your own and if you getting some problem in there then SO here for you Goo day again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your password is stored in a character array named password. Then you can do the validation as follows including string.h:

```
int digitflag=0;
int upperflag=0;
int lowerflag=0;
int i;
if(strlen(password)<8)
{
printf("Length is less than 8");
}
else
{
    for(i=0;i<strlen(password);i++)
        {
           if(isdigit(password[i]))
           digitflag=1;
           if(isupper(password[i]))
           upperflag=1;
           if(islower(password[i]))
           lowerflag=1;
        }
      if(digitflag==0)
      printf("No digits");
      if(upperflag==0)
      printf("No Upper Case Letters");
      if(lowerflag==0)
      printf("No Lower Case Letters");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should check length of the password if it is less than 8 then you can give a error message.And for digit,uppercase and lowercase character you can use separate flag and then you have to read each character set appropriate flag.When you finished reading all character you can check whether all flags are set or not and take appropriate actions.

Comment: A very discreet answer indeed! :)